# Spring Properties in Version Control

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot

I've created the following properties files that are all checked into git:

```
   **application.properties**  
    spring.application.name=my-service  
    spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true    
    spring.cloud.config.uri=${CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}
    spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled=false

   **application-dev.properties**  
    spring.cloud.config.enabled=false  
    eureka.client.enabled=false  
    spring.application.name=my-service  
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_URL:http://localhost:3306/db_example}
    spring.datasource.username=dev
    spring.datasource.password=local
```

In production all configurations are retrieved from the config server.

Questions regarding this setup:

1. Developer B starts working on this project and clones it. Unfortunately his local database is on another port with another user. How would he change it? Use the specified environment variables?
2. Developer B has an issue in a filter and wants to set spring security trace on DEBUG. Again, how can he modify it without polluting the git repository?

What options I see:

1. Environment variables
2. A git ignores -local.properties file that every developer can setup locally. There I can set trace levels etc.

Something I'm missing? I want a ready-to-go dev profile, but of course adjustments are necessary for every individual developers machine.

Comment: You can also pass properties at the command line, e.g. `-Dprop=value`. Those should override the default properties and thus might be viable for smaller changes. Besides that as far as I know there's a lookup order for properties files so you could have spring boot to look for a local (not committed) file with user specific settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define profiles for building spring which would be passed to project build time.
So define as much as profile properties file you like as :

```
application-prod.properties
application-user1.properties
application-user2.properties
application-user3.properties
```

you can load your Properties by passing VM-Options in your project configuration as

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=user2
```

Please note that you can define common properties which will be used by all profiles as:

```
application.properties
```

and set your default profile in `application.properties` as:

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Comment: In this case I'd have to make sure that developers dont push their properties to the repo though.

Comment: please let them push their properties. it doesn't matter. in your build time, you specify which properties to be loaded. I'm using this solution in my project to specify deploy environment and development environment properties which both of them are pushed to git repository.

Comment: Developers should review their commits before they push. If they push faulty code (bad ports). Its the developers responsabillity. This should get cought in PR reviews

Comment: Whatever they push will not run on production since you set your default profile in `application.properties`. that means if you do not set profile in the build configuration, the `application-prod.properties` will be loaded. I have updated the answer

Comment: @ThomasAndolf by default Spring will load `application-prod.properties`. So you should not let developers change or modify the file.

Comment: If two developers decide to push a -local profile with their trace preferences they'll have fun canceling out their merge conflicts. And at the end there's one file for every developer in the repo. Can you catch that? Sure. Should they review their push requests? Sure. But people are lazy with add all and push it.

Comment: I have mentioned that in my answer that each developer will have it's own properties and profile. So, they will never encounter any conflicts with each other.

Comment: Developers should do pull requests and review code before it goes inte master.

Answer (score 0):

Each user might have its  proper Database scheme based on. :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:myql://host:port/database_${user.lowername}


spring.datasource.username=database_${user.lowername}
spring.datasource.password=database_${user.lowername}
```

$user is an environment variable stored in the os itself

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple different ways at my company:

1. Environment variables like you have in your example
2. JVM options like *-DuserDatasourceUrl=jdbc:mysql:http://localhost:3306/db_example* in
   the project's run configuration. This still requires work by
   developers to provide their database configuration, but with a good "how to
   run locally" section in the README.md it might be another option for
   you.

Spring Boot's [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) documentation was really helpful for us in understanding our options and the PropertySource order.

Comment: I just feel that using command line arguments can be quite cumbersome. Putting all kind of log levels in there. Granted, most IDEs will save it as configuration too, so that might be good enough